# Unit testing AngularJS service results in unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am adding unit tests for a AngularJS service that returns a constructor similar to this example:

```
 angular.module('utilities', []).
     factory('Toy', [function () {

         var Toy = function (arg) {
             this.arg = arg;
             this.isActive = true;
         };

         Toy.prototype.stop = function () {
             this.isActive = false;
         };

         return Toy;
     }]);
```

Here's the current Jasmine spec:

```
 describe('toy-service tests', function () {

     var toyFactory, toy;

     beforeEach(function () {
         module('utilities');
         inject(function($injector) {
             toyFactory = $injector.get('Toy');
         });
     });

     it('should create a new utilities.Toy instance', function () {
         toy = new toyFactory(1);
         expect(toy).toBeDefined();
         expect(toy.arg).toEqual(1);
         expect(toy.isActive).toBeTruthy();
     });
 });
```

The unit test fails due to 'Error: Unknown provider: ToyProvider <- Toy'

After a day of reading other unit testing posts, I still have no idea why. Any suggestions?

**Additional information:**

I pulled this service definition and and spec into a test script in a copy of angular-phonecat. To my surprise, the test passes without applying any of the suggested changes when run in angular-phonecat.

**The cause of the error:**

The error was due to my newness with AngularJS and adding services to the utilities module in multiple files. I was redefining the utilities module in each source file thus wiping out its previous properties. Only the alphabetically last source file's definition of the utilities module was available for testing. Because toy-service.js was not the last source file, the Toy service was unavailable.

The toy test worked in angular-phonecat because there are no other utilities module files in that app.

Thanks go to Mark Sheretta who helped me debug this problem.

Comment: Try putting module('utilities') in separate before each. Put this on beggining: beforeEach(module('utilities'));

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
beforeEach(module('utilities'));

beforeEach(inject(function(Toy) {
   toyFactory = Toy;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The module function used when you are calling

```
beforeEach(module('utilities'));
```

is defined in angular-mocks, not in the core Angular library.  Therefore, you need to make sure that the angular-mocks.js file is loaded by your test runner when running this test.

I was able to successfully run this test after configuring my test runner as described above.